# FOSCKEditorBundle styles not apply

Tags: php, symfony, uikit, ckeditor4.x

I am using FOSCKEditorBundle for my Symfony4 Project. Installation process went well. Also the base configuration like toolbars etc. are good.
But I'm trying to apply custom styles to some html elements. This seems not to work. Maybe I did something wrong...

This is my config:

```
fos_ck_editor:
    input_sync: true
    default_config: base_config
    auto_inline: false

    # Defines the different configs to apply them to the form fields
    configs:
        minimal_config:
            toolbar: 'minimal_toolbar'
            stylesSet: 'uikit'
        base_config:
            toolbar: 'base_toolbar'
            stylesSet: 'uikit'
        advanced_config:
            toolbar: 'advanced_toolbar'
            stylesSet: 'uikit'

     # Defines the different toolbars to reuse them for the different configs
    toolbars:
        configs:
            minimal_toolbar: ['@styles']
            base_toolbar: ['@styles', '@link', '@lists']
            advanced_toolbar: ['@styles', '@link', '@lists', '@indention', '@specials']
        items:
            styles: ['Bold', 'Italic']
            link: ['Link', 'Unlink']
            lists: ['BulletedList']
            indention: ['Indent', 'Outdent']
            specials: ['Table', 'Source', 'Format']

    # Defines the custom styles for uikit
    styles:
        uikit:
            - { name: "CSS Style", element: "table", attributes: { class: "uk-table" }}
            - { name: "CSS Style", element: "table", attributes: { border: "0" }}
```

Maybe someone had the same problem and can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote :

> This seems not to work

Are you sure it does not works ? From [CKEditor4 official documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_styles.html#how-do-i-use-the-styles-on-images-tables-or-other-elements):

> If you added some custom style definitions for objects such *as tables* or images, **you need to select these objects first** before you will be able to apply the style. Object styles are only shown in the Styles drop-down list and can be applied after the element was selected in the editor as shown in the image below when the table is selected.

Notice you have twice `CSS Style` name in your configuration. If you want to apply two attributes on `CSS Style` entry, I suggest you to write

```
- { name: "CSS Style", element: "table", attributes: { class: "uk-table", border: "0" }}
```